# Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, string-concatenation

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Year  quarter
2000       q2
2001       q3
```

How do I add a new column by combining these columns to get the following dataframe?

```
Year  quarter  period
2000       q2  2000q2
2001       q3  2001q3
```

Comment: Searchers: [here's a similar question with more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1227):

If both columns are strings, you can concatenate them directly:

```
df["period"] = df["Year"] + df["quarter"]
```

If one (or both) of the columns are not string typed, you should convert it (them) first,

```
df["period"] = df["Year"].astype(str) + df["quarter"]
```

#### **Beware of NaNs when doing this!**

---

If you need to join multiple string columns, you can use `agg`:

```
df['period'] = df[['Year', 'quarter', ...]].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

Where "-" is the separator.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple columns together without typing out all the columns? Let's say `add(dataframe.iloc[:, 0:10])` for example?

Comment: @Heisenberg That should be possible with the Python builtin ``sum``.

Comment: @silvado could you please make an example for adding multiple columns?
Thank you

Comment: Be careful, you need to apply map(str) to all columns that are not string in the first place. if quarter was a number you would do
   `dataframe["period"] = dataframe["Year"].map(str) + dataframe["quarter"].map(str)`
map is just applying string conversion to all entries.

Comment: @OzgurOzturk Based on the OP's example, it seems that the data in quarter are already strings. If not you need to convert of course.

Comment: Also facilitates the easy addition of a separator. For example the separator '__':
```dataframe["period"] = dataframe["Year"].map(str) + '__' + dataframe["quarter"]```

Comment: This solution can create problems iy you have nan values, e careful

Comment: this can create problems with text which needs utf-8 encoding

Comment: I'm getting the `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I use this solution - how can I do this without triggering that warning?

Comment: This solution is much faster than using the apply function.

Comment: Not sure which version of python this would work for, but this didn't work. It created a list of the joined list in every row cell of the new column.

Comment: In general, `astype` should be used for casting pandas.Series to another type. So instead of `.map(str)`, use `.astype(str)`.

Comment: what to of NaNs? Is there a solution to ignore them?

Comment: If both the column are string then df['year_qtr'] = df['year'].str.cat(df['qtr'],sep='_')

Comment: Instead of `.agg...` use `.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)`. This was 5 times faster than the .agg version.

Comment: @c1c1c1 see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269756/6589617

Comment: ^^ and you can combine it with str convertig:
.apply(lambda x: '__'.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

Comment: If there are NAs: `.fillna('').agg('-'.join, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 408):

### Small data-sets (< 150rows)

```
[''.join(i) for i in zip(df["Year"].map(str),df["quarter"])]
```

or slightly slower but more compact:

```
df.Year.str.cat(df.quarter)
```

### Larger data sets (> 150rows)

```
df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']
```

---

**UPDATE:** Timing graph Pandas 0.23.4

[image]

Let's test it on 200K rows DF:

```
In [250]: df
Out[250]:
   Year quarter
0  2014      q1
1  2015      q2

In [251]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5)

In [252]: df.shape
Out[252]: (200000, 2)
```

**UPDATE:** new timings using Pandas 0.19.0

**Timing** without CPU/GPU optimization (sorted from fastest to slowest):

```
In [107]: %timeit df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop

In [106]: %timeit df['Year'].map(str) + df['quarter']
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [108]: %timeit df.Year.str.cat(df.quarter)
10 loops, best of 3: 189 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit df.loc[:, ['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 567 ms per loop

In [110]: %timeit df[['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 584 ms per loop

In [111]: %timeit df[['Year','quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 24.7 s per loop
```

**Timing** using CPU/GPU optimization:

```
In [113]: %timeit df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']
10 loops, best of 3: 53.3 ms per loop

In [114]: %timeit df['Year'].map(str) + df['quarter']
10 loops, best of 3: 65.5 ms per loop

In [115]: %timeit df.Year.str.cat(df.quarter)
10 loops, best of 3: 79.9 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit df.loc[:, ['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 230 ms per loop

In [117]: %timeit df[['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 230 ms per loop

In [118]: %timeit df[['Year','quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.38 s per loop
```

Answer contribution by [@anton-vbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7386332/anton-vbr)

Comment: What difference between 261 and 264 in your timing?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov apparently 100ms out of nowhere :)

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, i guess it's a mixture of two timings - one used CPU/GPU optimization, another one didn't. I've updated my answer and put both timing sets there...

Comment: This use of .sum() fails If all columns look like they could be integers (ie are string forms of integers). Instead, it seems pandas converts them back to numeric before summing!

Comment: @CPBL, try this approach: `df.T.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=''))`

Comment: @MaxU How did you go about the CPU/GPU optimization? Is that just a more powerful computer or is it something you did with code?

Comment: @user3374113, it has nothing to do with the code. My notebook has a switch which switches on GPU and enables Intel Turbo Boost Technology

Comment: @MaxU, have you tried comparing the `.str.cat()` method?

Comment: Late to the party. But I'm confused as to how `df['Year'].map(str)` works. Does `str` serve as an `arg` and it basically just sets everything in the `df['Year']` as string? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu, exactly, it does the same thing as df['Year'].astype(str)

Comment: And df['period'] = [''.join(x) for x in zip(df['Year'], df['quarter'])] ?

Comment: @MaxU - I've found that `apply(str)` is typically faster than `astype(str)`, would be interesting to see how that stacks up here.

Comment: @MaxU could you help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Comment: I'm curious if there is an easy way to make any of these answers amenable to providing an arbitrary list of column names.

Comment: @jflournoy, pardon, I’m not sure I understood your question. Could you please explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm curious how you would implement the best performers, `[111]` and `[107]` above, in a function that takes as input a list of arbitrary length. I guess it's obvious one could loop through the list to iteratively build up the full concatenated strings, but thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 326):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
df['period'] = df[['Year', 'quarter']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Yields this dataframe

```
   Year quarter  period
0  2014      q1  2014q1
1  2015      q2  2015q2
```

This method generalizes to an arbitrary number of string columns by replacing `df[['Year', 'quarter']]` with any column slice of your dataframe, e.g. `df.iloc[:,0:2].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)`.

You can check more information about apply() method [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: `lambda x: ''.join(x)` is just `''.join`, no?

Comment: @DSM no.  here we are taking each row of the df[['Year', 'quarter']] and passing it as series to join, and join concatenates the elements in the series.

Comment: @OzgurOzturk: the point is that the lambda part of the `lambda x: ''.join(x)` construction doesn't do anything; it's like using `lambda x: sum(x)` instead of just `sum`.

Comment: @Russ, if you wanted to join these strings based on some criteria i.e. `join if string != "some_string"` how could you add that?

Comment: Confirmed same result when using `''.join`, i.e.: `df['period'] = df[['Year', 'quarter']].apply(''.join, axis=1)`.

Comment: This solution gives me a `TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found'`, as I want to combine an integer categorical variable with a string category.

Comment: @Archie `join` takes only `str` instances in an iterable. Use a `map` to convert them all into `str` and then use `join`.

Comment: This solution ended up being reasonably slower for me than using the `df['Foo'].map(function) + '-' + df['Bar'].map(function)` approach. For ~48k rows applying a join along axis 1 took 1.15s whereas the other approach takes 100ms. Not unreasonable on a small dataset, but if you are working with a lot of data that can make a big difference.

Comment: '-'.join(x.map(str))

Comment: Similarly df['period'] = [''.join(x) for x in zip(df['Year'], df['quarter'])] works too which may be faster.

Comment: This is the best and most versatile answer, given that the columns to be joined may need to be dynamic and not static and this solution makes that possible.

Answer (score 201):

The method [`cat()` of the `.str` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat) works really well for this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["2014", "q1"], 
...                    ["2015", "q3"]],
...                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter'))
>>> print(df)
   Year Quarter
0  2014      q1
1  2015      q3
>>> df['Period'] = df.Year.str.cat(df.Quarter)
>>> print(df)
   Year Quarter  Period
0  2014      q1  2014q1
1  2015      q3  2015q3
```

`cat()` even allows you to add a separator so, for example, suppose you only have integers for year and period, you can do this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[2014, 1],
...                    [2015, 3]],
...                   columns=('Year', 'Quarter'))
>>> print(df)
   Year Quarter
0  2014       1
1  2015       3
>>> df['Period'] = df.Year.astype(str).str.cat(df.Quarter.astype(str), sep='q')
>>> print(df)
   Year Quarter  Period
0  2014       1  2014q1
1  2015       3  2015q3
```

Joining multiple columns is just a matter of passing either a list of series or a dataframe containing all but the first column as a parameter to `str.cat()` invoked on the first column (Series):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     [['USA', 'Nevada', 'Las Vegas'],
...      ['Brazil', 'Pernambuco', 'Recife']],
...     columns=['Country', 'State', 'City'],
... )
>>> df['AllTogether'] = df['Country'].str.cat(df[['State', 'City']], sep=' - ')
>>> print(df)
  Country       State       City                   AllTogether
0     USA      Nevada  Las Vegas      USA - Nevada - Las Vegas
1  Brazil  Pernambuco     Recife  Brazil - Pernambuco - Recife
```

Do note that if your pandas dataframe/series has null values, you need to include the parameter na_rep to replace the NaN values with a string, otherwise the combined column will default to NaN.

Comment: This seems way better (maybe more efficient, too) than `lambda` or `map`; also it just reads most cleanly.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? I get ValueError: Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword? in pandas-0.23.4.
Thanks!

Comment: @QinqingLiu, I retested these with pandas-0.23.4 and they seem work. The `sep` parameter is only necessary if you intend to separate the parts of the concatenated string. If you get an error, please show us your failing example.

Comment: @LeoRochael can i do a newline instead of '-' with sep keyword?

Comment: @arun-menon: I don't see why not. In the last example above you could do `.str.cat(df[['State', 'City']], sep ='\n')`, for example. I haven't tested it yet, though.

Answer (score 44):

Use of a lamba function this time with string.format().

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'Quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
print df
df['YearQuarter'] = df[['Year','Quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
print df

  Quarter  Year
0      q1  2014
1      q2  2015
  Quarter  Year YearQuarter
0      q1  2014      2014q1
1      q2  2015      2015q2
```

This allows you to work with non-strings and reformat values as needed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'Quarter': [1, 2]})
print df.dtypes
print df

df['YearQuarter'] = df[['Year','Quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}q{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
print df

Quarter     int64
Year       object
dtype: object
   Quarter  Year
0        1  2014
1        2  2015
   Quarter  Year YearQuarter
0        1  2014      2014q1
1        2  2015      2015q2
```

Comment: Much quicker: .apply(''.join(x), axis=1)

Comment: This solution worked great for my needs since I had to do some formatting.


`df_game['formatted_game_time'] = df_game[['wday', 'month', 'day', 'year', 'time']].apply(lambda x: '{}, {}/{}/{} @ {}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]), axis=1)`

Answer (score 24):

generalising to multiple columns, why not:

```
columns = ['whatever', 'columns', 'you', 'choose']
df['period'] = df[columns].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Looks cool but what if I want to add a delimiter between the strings, like '-'?

Comment: @Odisseo maybe create a delimiter column?

Answer (score 19):

You can use lambda:

```
combine_lambda = lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x.Year, x.quarter)
```

And then use it with creating the new column:

```
df['period'] = df.apply(combine_lambda, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 15):

Let us suppose your  `dataframe` is `df` with columns **`Year`** and **`Quarter`**.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter':'q1 q2 q3 q4'.split(), 'Year':'2000'})
```

Suppose we want to see the dataframe;

```
df
>>>  Quarter    Year
   0    q1      2000
   1    q2      2000
   2    q3      2000
   3    q4      2000
```

Finally, concatenate the **`Year`** and the **`Quarter`** as follows.

```
df['Period'] = df['Year'] + ' ' + df['Quarter']
```

You can now `print` **`df`**  to see the resulting dataframe.

```
df
>>>  Quarter    Year    Period
    0   q1      2000    2000 q1
    1   q2      2000    2000 q2
    2   q3      2000    2000 q3
    3   q4      2000    2000 q4
```

If you do not want the space between the year and quarter, simply remove it by doing;

```
df['Period'] = df['Year'] + df['Quarter']
```

Comment: Specified as strings `df['Period'] = df['Year'].map(str) + df['Quarter'].map(str)`

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Series cannot perform the operation +` when I run either `df2['filename'] = df2['job_number'] + '.' + df2['task_number']` or `df2['filename'] = df2['job_number'].map(str) + '.' + df2['task_number'].map(str)`.

Comment: However, `df2['filename'] = df2['job_number'].astype(str) + '.' + df2['task_number'].astype(str)` did work.

Comment: @KarlBaker, I think you did not have strings in your input. But I am glad you figured that out. If you look at the example `dataframe` that I created above, you will see that all the columns are `string`s.

Comment: What exactly is the point of this solution, since it's identical to the top answer?

Answer (score 14):

Although the @silvado answer is good if you change `df.map(str)` to `df.astype(str)` it will be faster:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})

In [131]: %timeit df["Year"].map(str)
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 us per loop

In [132]: %timeit df["Year"].astype(str)
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.2 us per loop
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is an implementation that I find very versatile:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'the', 'quick', 'brown'],
   ...:                    [1, 'fox', 'jumps', 'over'], 
   ...:                    [2, 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']],
   ...:                   columns=['c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])

In [3]: def str_join(df, sep, *cols):
   ...:     from functools import reduce
   ...:     return reduce(lambda x, y: x.astype(str).str.cat(y.astype(str), sep=sep), 
   ...:                   [df[col] for col in cols])
   ...: 

In [4]: df['cat'] = str_join(df, '-', 'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   c0   c1     c2     c3                cat
0   0  the  quick  brown  0-the-quick-brown
1   1  fox  jumps   over   1-fox-jumps-over
2   2  the   lazy    dog     2-the-lazy-dog
```

Comment: FYI: This method works great with Python 3, but gives me trouble in Python 2.

Answer (score 12):

more efficient is

```
def concat_df_str1(df):
    """ run time: 1.3416s """
    return pd.Series([''.join(row.astype(str)) for row in df.values], index=df.index)
```

and here is a time test:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from time import time


def concat_df_str1(df):
    """ run time: 1.3416s """
    return pd.Series([''.join(row.astype(str)) for row in df.values], index=df.index)


def concat_df_str2(df):
    """ run time: 5.2758s """
    return df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)


def concat_df_str3(df):
    """ run time: 5.0076s """
    df = df.astype(str)
    return df[0] + df[1] + df[2] + df[3] + df[4] + \
           df[5] + df[6] + df[7] + df[8] + df[9]


def concat_df_str4(df):
    """ run time: 7.8624s """
    return df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(1000000).reshape(100000, 10))
    df = df.astype(int)

    time1 = time()
    df_en = concat_df_str4(df)
    print('run time: %.4fs' % (time() - time1))
    print(df_en.head(10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

final, when `sum`(concat_df_str2) is used, the result is not simply concat, it will trans to integer.

Comment: +1 Neat solution, this also allows us to specify the columns: e.g. `df.values[:, 0:3]` or `df.values[:, [0,2]]`.

Answer (score 7):

Using `zip` could be even quicker:

```
df["period"] = [''.join(i) for i in zip(df["Year"].map(str),df["quarter"])]
```

Graph:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})

myfuncs = {
"df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']":
    lambda: df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter'],
"df['Year'].map(str) + df['quarter']":
    lambda: df['Year'].map(str) + df['quarter'],
"df.Year.str.cat(df.quarter)":
    lambda: df.Year.str.cat(df.quarter),
"df.loc[:, ['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)":
    lambda: df.loc[:, ['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1),
"df[['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)":
    lambda: df[['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1),
    "df[['Year','quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)":
    lambda: df[['Year','quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1),
    "[''.join(i) for i in zip(dataframe['Year'].map(str),dataframe['quarter'])]":
    lambda: [''.join(i) for i in zip(df["Year"].map(str),df["quarter"])]
}

d = defaultdict(dict)
step = 10
cont = True
while cont:
    lendf = len(df); print(lendf)
    for k,v in myfuncs.items():
        iters = 1
        t = 0
        while t < 0.2:
            ts = timeit.repeat(v, number=iters, repeat=3)
            t = min(ts)
            iters *= 10
        d[k][lendf] = t/iters
        if t > 2: cont = False
    df = pd.concat([df]*step)

pd.DataFrame(d).plot().legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15))
plt.yscale('log'); plt.xscale('log'); plt.ylabel('seconds'); plt.xlabel('df rows')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution uses an intermediate step **compressing two columns of the DataFrame to a single column containing a list** of the values.
This works not only for strings but for all kind of column-dtypes

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
df['list']=df[['Year','quarter']].values.tolist()
df['period']=df['list'].apply(''.join)
print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
   Year quarter        list  period
0  2014      q1  [2014, q1]  2014q1
1  2015      q2  [2015, q2]  2015q2
```

Comment: looks like other dtypes won't work. I got a  TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found

Comment: apply first a cast to string. The join operation works only for strings

Comment: This solution won't work to combine two columns with different dtype, see my answer for the correct solution for such case.

Comment: Instead of `.apply(''.join)` why not use `.str.join('')`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my summary of the above solutions to concatenate / combine two columns with int and str value into a new column, using a separator between the values of columns. Three solutions work for this purpose.

```
# be cautious about the separator, some symbols may cause "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal".
# e.g. ";;" as separator would raise the SyntaxError

separator = "&&" 

# pd.Series.str.cat() method does not work to concatenate / combine two columns with int value and str value. This would raise "AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype"

df["period"] = df["Year"].map(str) + separator + df["quarter"]
df["period"] = df[['Year','quarter']].apply(lambda x : '{} && {}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
df["period"] = df.apply(lambda x: f'{x["Year"]} && {x["quarter"]}', axis=1)
```

Comment: At least your first solution does not work (any more?). I use: `df["period"] = (df["Year"].astype(str) + separator + df["quarter"].astype(str)).astype('category')`

Answer (score 5):

my take....

```
listofcols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df['combined_cols'] = ''

for column in listofcols:
    df['combined_cols'] = df['combined_cols'] + ' ' + df[column]
'''
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to this code snippet. Adding only code answers encourages people to use code they don't understand and doesn't help them learn.

Answer (score 3):

When combining columns with strings by concatenating them using the addition operator `+` if any is `NaN` then entire output will be `NaN` so use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```py
df["join"] = "some" + df["col"].fillna(df["val_if_nan"])
```

Answer (score 2):

As many have mentioned previously, you must convert each column to string and then use the plus operator to combine two string columns. You can get a large performance improvement by using NumPy.

```
%timeit df['Year'].values.astype(str) + df.quarter
71.1 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['Year'].astype(str) + df['quarter']
565 ms ± 22.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I'd like to use the numpyified version but I'm getting an error: **Input**: `df2['filename'] = df2['job_number'].values.astype(str) + '.' + df2['task_number'].values.astype(str)` --> **Output**: `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')`. Both job_number and task_number are ints.

Comment: That's because you are combining two numpy arrays. It works if you combine an numpy array with pandas Series. as `df['Year'].values.astype(str) + df.quarter`

Answer (score 2):

One can use *assign* method of *DataFrame*:

```
df= (pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']}).
  assign(period=lambda x: x.Year+x.quarter ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @geher answer but with any separator you like:

```py
SEP = " "
INPUT_COLUMNS_WITH_SEP = ",sep,".join(INPUT_COLUMNS).split(",")

df.assign(sep=SEP)[INPUT_COLUMNS_WITH_SEP].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def madd(x):
    """Performs element-wise string concatenation with multiple input arrays.

    Args:
        x: iterable of np.array.

    Returns: np.array.
    """
    for i, arr in enumerate(x):
        if type(arr.item(0)) is not str:
            x[i] = x[i].astype(str)
    return reduce(np.core.defchararray.add, x)
```

For example:

```
data = list(zip([2000]*4, ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4']))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Year', 'quarter'])
df['period'] = madd([df[col].values for col in ['Year', 'quarter']])

df

    Year    quarter period
0   2000    q1  2000q1
1   2000    q2  2000q2
2   2000    q3  2000q3
3   2000    q4  2000q4
```

Comment: NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined

Comment: `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.combine_first`.

```
df['Period'] = df['Year'].combine_first(df['Quarter'])
```

Comment: This is not correct. `.combine_first` will result in either the value from `'Year'` being stored in `'Period'`, or, if it is Null, the value from `'Quarter'`. It will not concatenate the two strings and store them in `'Period'`.

Answer (score 0):

### [DataFrame.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)

For a little terse code, we can use `.eval()`. We can concatenate two (or more) string dtype columns horizontally using the `+` operator as follows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'B': ['1', '2', '3']}, dtype='string')
df['C'] = df.eval("A + B")
```

You can even include the new column assignment inside the evaluated expression (which also opens up the possibility to do it in-place).

```py
df = df.eval('C = A + B')
df.eval('C = A + B', inplace=True)
```

`eval` doesn't allow a similarly terse way to add delimiters; however, we can call `str.cat()` (which has the `sep=` kwarg) inside the numerical expression.

```py
df = df.eval("D = A.str.cat([B, C], '_')")
```

which produces the following output (where columns, `A`, `B` and `C` are concatenated horizontally):

[image: result]

### When to use vectorized concat vs explicit loop

There are major string concatenation methods given on this page:

- vectorized `+`: `df['A'] + df['B']`
- string formatting in a loop (N.B. converting the columns into lists makes the loop faster):

  ```
  [f"{x}{y}" for x,y in zip(df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist())])]
  ```
- vectorized `str.cat()`: `df['A'].str.cat(df['B'])`

As the following figure shows, vectorized concatenation (via `+`) is fastest if the strings being concatenated are short such as in the OP. However, if the strings are long (e.g. each cell contains a tweet or a book excerpt), then an explicit Python loop (use f-string in a list comprehension) is the fastest.

[image: perfplot]

Code to reproduce the above figure:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,5))
for ax, s, title in zip(axs, ('a'*1000, 'a'), ("long", "short")):
    plt.sca(ax)
    perfplot.plot(
        kernels=[lambda df: df.assign(C=df['A'] + '_' + df['B']),
                 lambda df: df.assign(C=df['A'].str.cat(df['B'], '_')),
                 lambda df: df.assign(C=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in zip(df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist())])],
        n_range=[2**k for k in range(18)],
        setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'A': [s]*n, 'B': [s]*n}),
        labels=["df['A'] + df['B']", "str.cat", "list comp"],
        xlabel="DataFrame length",
        title=f"When the strings are {title}", 
        equality_check=pd.DataFrame.equals)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("string_concat_perf.png")
```