# Python pandas pivot multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

### Input

I have the following file `input.txt`:

```
D E F G H
a 1 b 1 4
a 1 c 1 5
b 2 c 2 6
```

### Desired output

How can I create a new data frame, that uses columns D and E as an index? I want a triangular matrix that looks something like this:

```
   a1 b1 c1 b2 c2
a1  0  4  5  0  0
b1     0  0  0  0
c1        0  0  0
b2           0  6
c2              0
```

### 1st attempt

I am importing the data frame and I am trying to do a pivot like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(
    'input.txt', index_col=[0,1], delim_whitespace=True,
    usecols=['D','E','F','G','H'])
df2 = df1.pivot(index=['D', 'E'], columns=['F','G'], values='H')
```

`df1` looks like this:

```
     F  G  H
D E         
a 1  b  1  4
  1  c  1  5
b 2  c  2  6
```

`df1.index` looks like this:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], [1, 2]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]],
           names=['D', 'E'])
```

`df2` fails to be generated and I get this error message:

```
`KeyError: "['D' 'E'] not in index"`
```

### 2nd attempt

I thought I had solved it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(
    'input.txt', delim_whitespace=True,
    usecols=['D','E','F','G','H'],
    dtype={'D':str, 'E':str, 'F':str, 'G':str, 'H':float},
    )
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='H', index=['D','E'], columns=['F','G'])
```

`pivot` looks like this:

```
F     b   c    
G     1   1   2
D E            
a 1   4   5 NaN
b 2 NaN NaN   6
```

But when I try to do this to convert it to a symmetric matrix:

```
pivot.add(df.T, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
```

Then I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

### 3rd attempt and solution

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-panda-python). It is also what @Moritz suggested, but I'm new to pandas and didn't understand his comment. I did this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(
    'input.txt', index_col=[0,1], delim_whitespace=True,
    usecols=['D','E','F','G','H'],
    dtype={'D':str, 'E':str, 'F':str, 'G':str, 'H':float}
    )
df1['DE'] = df1['D']+df1['E']
df1['FG'] = df1['F']+df1['G']
df2 = df1.pivot(index='DE', columns='FG', values='H')
```

This data frame is generated:

```
FG  b1  c1  c2
DE            
a1   4   5 NaN
b2 NaN NaN   6
```

Afterwards I do `df3 = df2.add(df2.T, fill_value=0).fillna(0)` to convert the triangular matrix to a symmetric matrix. Is generating new columns really the easiest way to accomplish what I want? My reason for doing all of this is that I want to generate a heat map with matplotlib and hence need the data to be in matrix form. The final matrix/dataframe looks like this:

```
    a1  b1  b2  c1  c2
a1   0   4   0   5   0
b1   4   0   0   0   0
b2   0   0   0   0   6
c1   5   0   0   0   0
c2   0   0   6   0   0
```

Comment: What if you try something like df ['D'].map(str) +df ['E'].map(str) etc.  ?

Comment: Please post the solution and what you are working on

Comment: Whoa, lot of stuff here now.  Would be helpful to remove the solved stuff and just leave the parts relevant to the current issue you are trying to solve.  Otherwise folks are going to waste time reading irrelevant aspects and might not even make it all the way to the the actual question...

Comment: @JohnE actually on second thought I think it will be beneficial for others to see all the mistakes I made?

Comment: @Moritz I realise now that you gave me the answer. I'm new to Pandas, so I didn't understand your comment. Can you leave an answer? I posted the solution under `EDIT2`.

Comment: I am too lazy right now. I will do that later on. Currently I do only have my tablet.