# Combine arbitrary number of columns into one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question is a general version of a specific case asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-panda-python).

I have a pandas dataframe with columns that contain integers. I'd like to concatenate all of those integers into a string in one column.

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19378497/368311), for particular columns, this works:

```
(dl['ungrd_dum'].map(str) +
 dl['mba_dum'].map(str) +
 dl['jd_dum'].map(str) +
 dl['ma_phd_dum'].map(str))
```

But suppose I have many (hundreds) of such columns, whose names are in a list `dummies`. I'm certain there's some cool pythonic way of doing this with one magical line that will do it all. I've tried using `map` with `dummies`, but haven't yet been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you should be able to do

```
df[dummies].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

Example:

```
In [12]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,100, 5), 'b':np.arange(5), 'c':np.random.randint(0,10,5)})
df
Out[12]:
    a  b  c
0   5  0  2
1  46  1  3
2  86  2  4
3  85  3  9
4  60  4  4
In [15]:

cols=['a','c']
df[cols].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
Out[15]:
0     52
1    463
2    864
3    859
4    604
dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

As @JohnE has pointed out you could call `sum` instead which will be faster:

```
df[cols].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

However, that will implicitly convert the dtype to `float64` so you'd have to cast back to `str` again and slice the decimal point off if necessary:

```
df[cols].astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(str).str[:-2]
```

Comment: Indeed, you understand perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: (Remember that you can use `''.join` instead of `lambda x: ''.join(x)`.)

Comment: @DSM indeed I sometimes forget when I don't need a lambda

Comment: @DSM, is that a pandas thing, or due to python syntax?

Comment: Why not just use `sum` once they are strings?  `df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @JohnE although that works the `dtype` is converted to `float64` the OP wanted `str` so you'd have to cast it back to `str` again but it's probably faster for large dfs

Comment: @EdChum  Ah, yeah, good point.  I was just thinking the syntax was a little simpler is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import add
reduce(add, (df[c].astype(str) for c in cols), "")
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0,100, 5), 
                   'b':np.arange(5), 
                   'c':np.random.randint(0,10,5)})

cols = ['a', 'c']


In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
    a  b  c
0   6  0  4
1  59  1  9
2  13  2  5
3  44  3  1
4  79  4  4

In [20]: reduce(add, (df[c].astype(str) for c in cols), "")
Out[20]: 
0     64
1    599
2    135
3    441
4    794
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to convert your Dataframe of numbers in a Dataframe of strings, as efficiently as possible:

```
dl = dl.astype(str)
```

Then, you're in the same situation [as this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571832/how-to-row-wise-concatenate-several-columns-containing-strings), and can use the same `Series.str` accessor techniques as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210048/1273938):

## `.str.cat()`

Using [`str.cat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) you could do:

dl['result'] = dl[dl.columns[0]].str.cat([dl[c] for c in dl.columns[1:]], sep=' ')

## `str.join()`

To use `.str.join()` you need a series of iterables, say tuples.

```
df['result'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(tuple, axis=1).str.join(' ')
```

Don't try the above with `list` instead of `tuple` or the `apply()` methdo will return a `Dataframe` and dataframes don't have the `.str` accessor like `Series`.

Comment: Cat seems to be faster for me. Lambda was taking around 3 sec for 1 iteration but cat took just 0.08 sec for the same iteration.