# How to row-wise concatenate several columns containing strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, string-concatenation

I have a specific series of datasets which come in the following general form:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': random.sample(xrange(1000), 3), 't0':['a', 'b', 'c'], 't1':['d','e','f'], 't2':['g','h','i'], 't3':['i','j', 'k']})
```

The number of *tn* columns (*t0, t1, t2 ... tn*) **varies depending on the dataset**, but is always <30.
My aim is to merge the content of the *tn* columns for each row so that I achieve this result (note that for readability I need to keep the whitespace between elements):

```
df['result'] = df.t0 +' '+df.t1+' '+df.t2+' '+ df.t3
```

[image]

So far so good. This code may be simple but it becomes clumsy and inflexible as soon as I receive another dataset, where the number of *tn* columns goes up. This is where my question comes in:

**Is there any other syntax to merge the content across multiple columns?** Something agnostic to the number columns, akin to:

```
df['result'] = ' '.join(df.ix[:,1:])
```

Basically, I want to achieve the same as the OP in the link below, but with whitespace between the strings:
[Concatenate row-wise across specific columns of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308933/r-concatenate-row-wise-across-specific-columns-of-dataframe)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32529152/5276797

Comment: Perfect! The solution suggested by Russ is flexible and simple. Thanks @IanS for pointing out that answer!

Comment: For two columns, this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911306/3903767] on the same question linked by @IanS is substantially faster using .str.cat

Answer (score 3):

The key to operate in columns (Series) of strings *en mass* is the [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) accessor.

I can think of two `.str` methods to do what you want.

## `str.cat()`

The first is [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html). You have to start from a series, but you can pass a list of series (unfortunately you can't pass a dataframe) to concatenate with an optional separator. Using your example:

```
column_names = df.columns[1:]  # skipping the first, numeric, column
series_list = [df[c] for c in column_names[1:]]
# concatenate:
df['result'] = series_list[0].str.cat(series_list[1:], sep=' ')
```

Or, in one line:

```
df['result'] = df[df.columns[1]].str.cat([df[c] for c in df.columns[2:]], sep=' ')
```

## `str.join()`

The second is the [`.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) method, which works like the standard Python method [`string.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), but for which you need to have a column (Series) of iterables, for example, a column of tuples, which we can get by applying `tuples` row-wise to a sub-dataframe of the columns you're interested in:

```
tuple_series = df[column_names].apply(tuple, axis=1)
df['result'] = tuple_series.str.join(' ')
```

Or, in one line:

```
df['result'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(tuple, axis=1).str.join(' ')
```

BTW, don't try the above with `list` instead of `tuple`. As of `pandas-0.20.1`, if the function passed into the `Dataframe.apply()` method returns a `list` and the returned list has the same number entries as the columns  of the original (sub)dataframe, `Dataframe.apply()` returns a `Dataframe` instead of a `Series`.

Answer (score 2):

Other than using `apply` to concatenate the strings, you can also use `agg` to do so.

```
df[df.columns[1:]].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
Out[118]: 
0    a d g i
1    b e h j
2    c f i k
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly alternative solution:

```
In [57]: df['result'] = df.filter(regex=r'^t').apply(lambda x: x.add(' ')).sum(axis=1).str.strip()

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
     n t0 t1 t2 t3   result
0   92  a  d  g  i  a d g i
1  916  b  e  h  j  b e h j
2  363  c  f  i  k  c f i k
```