# Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, row, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
 0    a        1        2        3        4
 1    a        3        4        5
 2    b        6        7        8
 3    c        7        7
```

What I want to do now is getting a new dataframe containing Column1 and a new columnA. This columnA should contain all values from columns 2 -(to) n (where n is the number of columns from Column2 to the end of the row) like this:

```
  Column1  ColumnA
0   a      1,2,3,4
1   a      3,4,5
2   b      6,7,8
3   c      7,7
```

How could I best approach this issue?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can call `apply` pass `axis=1` to `apply` row-wise, then convert the dtype to `str` and `join`:

```
In [153]:
df['ColumnA'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1
)
df

Out[153]:
  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  ColumnA
0       a        1        2        3        4  1,2,3,4
1       a        3        4        5      NaN    3,4,5
2       b        6        7        8      NaN    6,7,8
3       c        7        7      NaN      NaN      7,7
```

Here I call `dropna` to get rid of the `NaN`, however we need to cast again to `int` so we don't end up with floats as str.

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work for me. I get duplicates. Therefore row 0 columnA is  1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

Comment: It seems like using iloc works for me. Theres no duplicates. df['ColumnA'] = df.iloc[:,source_col_loc+1:source_col_loc+4].apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: For future visitors wanting to just combine just some columns (and control order) you can replace `df[df.columns[1:]]` with `df[['Column4','Column1']]`

Answer (score 23):

I propose to use `.assign`

```
df2 = df.assign(ColumnA = df.Column2.astype(str) + ', ' + \
  df.Column3.astype(str) + ', ' df.Column4.astype(str) + ', ' \
  df.Column4.astype(str) + ', ' df.Column5.astype(str))
```

it's simple, maybe long but it worked for me

Comment: Also, if you are doing it for tonnes of data, it is much faster than lambda

Answer (score 12):

If you have lot of columns say - 1000 columns in dataframe and you want to merge few columns based on `particular column name` e.g. -`Column2` in question and arbitrary no. of columns after that column (e.g. here 3 columns after `'Column2` inclusive of `Column2` as OP asked).

We can get position of column using [`.get_loc()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas.Index.get_loc) - as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941406/pandas-how-to-get-position-of-columns)

```
source_col_loc = df.columns.get_loc('Column2') # column position starts from 0

df['ColumnA'] = df.iloc[:,source_col_loc+1:source_col_loc+4].apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

df

Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  ColumnA
0       a        1        2        3        4  1,2,3,4
1       a        3        4        5      NaN    3,4,5
2       b        6        7        8      NaN    6,7,8
3       c        7        7      NaN      NaN      7,7
```

To remove `NaN`, use [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) or [`.fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 10):

## **apply() is 100X slower than agg()**

Do NOT use apply, it does not scale well. Instead use [df.agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html). Using apply() will take seconds, but agg() will take milliseconds (ms).

### Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def createList(r1, r2):
    return np.arange(r1, r2+1, 1)

sample_data = createList(1, 100_000) # a list of 100,000 values

test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [sample_data]
)

test_df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))) #3.47 s ± 24.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

test_df.astype(str).agg(', '.join, axis=1) #34.8 ms ± 407 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As you can see from this sample, apply() took an average time of 3.47 seconds whereas agg() took an average time of 34.8 milliseconds. The gap in performance will become bigger as more data is added too.

*Note, I used %%timeit in jupyter notebook to get the run time for each method.

Comment: Already tested that and I can confirm that it is much faster.

Comment: Could you share a reproducible code that applies your suggestion to multiple ad-hoc column aggregation? Where to define specific column names in your answer?

Comment: @bonCodigo could you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: Try, happy to take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75482636/1389394

Comment: for those looking for simpler syntax for aggregate function: df['FullName'] = df[['First_Name', 'Last_Name']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)