# Pandas Get Non-Null Values From Row Into One Cell

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B': [4,0], 'C': [1,2]})
a
    A   B   C
0   1   4   1
1   2   0   2
```

I would like to create a new column `D` containing the non-null values (per row) separated by columns. Like this:

```
    A   B   C    D
0   1   4   1    1,4,1
1   2   0   2    1,0,2
```

In reality, I will have many columns.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you need `df.apply(lambda x :','.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative:

```
a['D'] = a.apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.dropna()
          .astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1)

print(a)
   A  B  C      D
0  1  4  1  1,4,1
1  2  0  2  2,0,2
```

Comment: `apply` with a lambda _and_ a loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data with NaN values
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan,2], 'B': [4,np.nan], 'C': [1,2]})
a
     A    B  C
0  NaN  4.0  1
1  2.0  NaN  2

# make new column with non-null values
a['D'] = a.apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if not np.isnan(val)], axis=1)
a
     A    B  C           D
0  NaN  4.0  1  [4.0, 1.0]
1  2.0  NaN  2  [2.0, 2.0]
```

Comment: Having trouble with this in pandas 0.20.3 and I'm not sure why, frankly.

Comment: I just tested again, also on 0.20.3, no issues.  What's the trouble you're having?

Comment: Very strange.  Mind trying with `a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B': [4,0], 'C': [1,2]}, dtype=float)`?

Comment: I get an error then: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1`.  I knocked it around a bit just now but couldn't figure out why it barfs when all values aren't `NaN`.  I'll have a look later.  Good observation, any ideas?

Comment: No, like I said I'm a bit stumped because your solution is pretty straightforward.  And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098470/7954504) solution works for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along the lines of the following:

```
combVals = []
a = a.T
for col in a.columns:
    combVals.append(str(a[col].dropna().astype(int).tolist())[1:-1])
a = a.T
a['D'] = combVals
print(a)
   A  B  C        D
0  1  4  1  1, 4, 1
1  2  0  2  2, 0, 2
```

You can remove the spaces in column `D` by doing: `a['D'] = a['D'].str.replace(' ','')`