# How to merge multiple column of same data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How to merge multiple column values into one column of same data frame and get new column with unique values.

```
 Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
 0    a        1        2        3        4
 1    a        3        4        5
 2    b        6        7        8
 3    c        7        7
```

Output:

```
Column A
a
a
b
c
1
3
6
7
2
4
5
8
```

Comment: Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
 0    a        1        2        3        4
 1    a        3        4        5
 2    b        6        7        8
 3    c        7        7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape, remove missinf values by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df.unstack().dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('A')
```

---

```
df1 = df.melt(value_name='A')[['A']].dropna().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
    A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   1
4   3
5   6
6   7
7   2
8   4
9   5
10  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it if you are ok using numpy.  This will handle either nans or empty strings in the original dataframe and is a bit faster than unstack
or melt.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'Column2': [1, 3, 6, 7],
                   'Column3': [2, 4, 7, 7],
                   'Column4': [3, 5, 8, np.nan],
                   'Column5': [4, '', '', np.nan]})

u = pd.unique(df.values.flatten(order='F'))
u = u[np.where(~np.isin(u, ['']) & ~pd.isnull(u))[0]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(u, columns=['A'])

print(df1)

    A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   1
4   3
5   6
6   7
7   2
8   4
9   5
10  8
```