# Python combine 2000+ csv columns into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to combine values of multiple columns into a single column. Suppose I have a csv with the following data

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,3,4
6,2,4,6
2,5,6,2
```

I want it to become a single column with the values concatenated separated by a blank space

```
col1
1 2 3 4
6 2 4 6
2 5 6 2
```

The number of columns is 2000+ so having the columns statically concatenated will not do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want such a design. But you can `aggregate` across `axis=1`

```
df.astype(str).agg(' '.join, 1).to_frame('col')
```

```
       col
0  1 2 3 4
1  6 2 4 6
2  2 5 6 2
```

Comment: I have records with 2k+ columns which varies 

I want to store my records in a database. Before querying to a database id like to concatenate the columns into a single string

Answer (score 0):

I would try using pandas. This will find all of the column names and then concat the values for each row across all columns and save it as a new dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
cols = df.columns
df = df[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

The output for this csv file

```
c1,c2,c3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Is

```
Index(['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], dtype='object')
0    1 2 3
1    4 5 6
2    7 8 9
```

Where the ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'] is all the column names concatenated.

Comment: Makes no sense to do `df[df.columns]`- it's redundant, just use `df`. Also, it's better to just make the whole `df.astype(str)` at once rather than do that partially for every series inside the `apply`. Finally, no need to do transform the pandas series into a Numpy array by using `row.values` - just use `row` right away.

Comment: @rafaelc you are right.. I just came across another problem using this solution. It would use col1 as the index.

Answer (score 0):

Setting things up:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#generating random int dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

First case(by hand):

```
str_df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(str) + " " + df.iloc[:, 1].apply(str) + " " + df.iloc[:, 2].apply(str) + " " + df.iloc[:, 3].apply(str)
```

Second case(generic):

```
str2_df = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(str)
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]):
  str2_df += " " + df.iloc[:, i].apply(str)
```

[the actual code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRFpx.png)

[the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzRA6.png)

Hope I have helped.

Comment: Even though this might work, it'll be pretty slow. Avoid looping through a `df` and accessing each row using `iloc[:, I]` - that goes against why the library was built in the first place (no loops!)