# Get all data from dataframe to a single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

This data frame consists of a lot of NAN values and in the latter columns, the data is sparse. But I want all the into a single column.

[image]

Like this,

```
Index    Seatblock 
1        A.B.C.D
2        A.B.C.D
3        A.B.C.D
4        A.B.C.D
5        A.B.C.D
```

1. Remove all NAN values. I tried `dropna` but it basically drops the columns off which also vanishes my sparse data.
2. Convert them into a single column, either using list or any python built-in function but I'm quite not able to find one.

Would be helpful. Thanks!

[Data is here](https://github.com/Irene-123/Data-sets/blob/main/Seatblocks.xlsx)

EDIT:
This is the output after applying the suggested code.
[image]

EDIT:

For example

```
Index Seatblock1 Seatblock2 Seatblock3
1       a.b.c.d    NAN         NAN
2       w.r.t.q    q.r.y.t     NAN
3       p.y.u.i    NAN         n.b.x.a
```

OUTPUT has to be:

```
Index Seatblock1  
1       a.b.c.d             
2       w.r.t.q    
3       p.y.u.i        
4       q.r.y.t
5       n.b.x.a
```

Like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)

Comment: No. I did checked. I don't want concatenation. I want the values to be stored down and down in one single column from all these columns

Comment: That's exactly what is being done in the other post. The only additional part is that you need to [drop the other columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to get just the `Index` and `Seatblock`.

Comment: what is the logic for converting values in all the different seatblock columns into a single column value: a.b.c.d?

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT a.b.c.d is the example for values in all columns. (resemblance)

Comment: @AKS But it gives me the dataframe as it is. Doesn't merge my data into one column

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't merge? After the `apply` command did you check `df[['Key', 'Seatblock']]` to see if that worked?

Comment: @AKS Please check the output in the edited answer

Comment: The length of columns is same and other values which needed to be put under first column are still sparse

Comment: @kirtipurohit Please try what I have mentioned in the comment above. `df[['Key', 'Seatblock']]`

Comment: How? Put it on the LHS of the code answered below?

Comment: At the end, you have written `df` instead of that use what is suggested above.

Comment: Gosh no, I don't want to concatentae values @AKS

Comment: I want all the sparse data into 1 single column

Comment: That's exactly what @Mutaz-MSFT was trying [to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279426/get-all-data-from-dataframe-to-a-single-column?noredirect=1#comment120673796_68279426) earlier. Please provide an adequate example of at least one row so that it becomes clear that exactly how all those columns should be combined into a single column.

Comment: Okay I have put an edit in the answer. Please check that @AKS

Comment: Yes. That's the logic I want

Comment: I see values like 'L:110:QQ:9,12' in the first row, it is not clear how that translate to 'a.b.c.d', please add clarity to explain the transformation you want to achieve with some examples from values in the original data frame.

Comment: That's just a quick example of what values are like in ahead columns. I don't need translation. As you said, I need the logic for getting all the values in 1 column. Please check the edit in the answer

Comment: Can you guys help? @AKS

Comment: @Mutaz-MSFT Can you guys help?

Comment: just posted an answer.. check if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example

data file:

```
Index,Seatblock1,Seatblock2,Seatblock3
1,a.b.c.d,,
2,w.r.t.q,q.r.y.t,
3,p.y.u.i,,n.b.x.a
```

load df:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
```

[image]

melt and drop na

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Index']).value.dropna()
```

output:

```
0    a.b.c.d
1    w.r.t.q
2    p.y.u.i
4    q.r.y.t
8    n.b.x.a
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much. Highly appreciable!