# Pandas Dataframe - convert columns to size classes and counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python and pandas.  I have a dataframe with columns that hold the number of seedlings for a particular size class:

```
Plot    Location    Year    Species 6-12_in 12-24_in    24-54_in    GreaterThan_54_in
1       VMU         2015    BC      3                   8
```

What I want to do is convert that dataframe to a format like this, where each size class (6-12_in, 12-24_in, 24-54_in, and GreaterThan_54_in) are numbered 1-4 and put into Size_Class/Count columns like this:

```
Plot    Location    Year    Species Size_Class  Count
1       VMU         2015    BC      1           3
1       VMU         2015    BC      3           8
```

I arbitrarily named the columns from dataframe 1, so

```
6-12_in =1
12-24_in =2
24-54_in=3
GreaterThan_54_in=4
```

I could easily write this looping through each row and building the new dataframe with if statements, but I feel like there must be a map/apply solution that is more efficient? I found this thread, which is kind of similar, but I'm not sure how to easily map the column names and make multiple rows?  [Merge multiple column values into one column in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas)

Any help to get started is appreciated- thank you!

Comment: where'd you get the sizes (1 and 3) from?

Comment: I arbitrarily named the columns from dataframe 1, so 6-12_in =1, 12-24_in =2, 24-54_in=3, and GreaterThan_54_in=4.  Updated the question with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# define dictionary to map the sizes to size class
d={'6-12_in' :1,
'12-24_in' :2,
'24-54_in':3,
'GreaterThan_54_in':4}


# melt the dataframe
df2=df.melt(id_vars=['Plot','Location','Year','Species'], 
            var_name='size_class', 
            value_name='count')
df2

# apply map 
df2['size_class']=df2['size_class'].map(d)

# drop where count is null
df2[df2['count'].notna()]
```

```
    Plot    Location    Year    Species     size_class  count
0      1    VMU         2015         BC              1    3.0
1      1    VMU         2015         BC              2    8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use melt to create a new row for each of your size columns.  Then group by Plot and assign each row an incremental id using `cumcount`.  Drop the null values after and you should get your desired result.

```
import pandas as pn
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Plot': [1],
 'Location': ['VMU'],
 'Year': [2015],
 'Species': ['BC'],
 '6-12_in': [3],
 '12-24_in': [np.nan],
 '24-54_in': [8],
 'GreaterThan_54_in': [np.nan]})

df = df.melt(id_vars=['Plot','Location','Year','Species'],
             var_name='Size_Class',
             value_name='Count')
df['Size_Class'] = df.groupby('Plot')['Size_Class'].cumcount()+1
df.dropna()
```

Output

```
   Plot Location  Year Species  Size_Class  Count
0     1      VMU  2015      BC           1    3.0
2     1      VMU  2015      BC           3    8.0
```