# Python: combining two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns, one has the year, and another has the month data, and I am trying to make one column from them (containing year and month).
Example:

```
click_year  
-----------
2016     

click_month   
-----------
11
```

I want to have

```
YearMonth 
-----------
201611
```

I tried

```
date['YearMonth'] = pd.concat((date.click_year, date.click_month))
```

but it gave me `"cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"` error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Bill's answer on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python) might be what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'click_year': ['2014', '2015'], 'click_month': ['10', '11']})

>>> df
click_month click_year
0          10       2014
1          11       2015

df['YearMonth'] = df[['click_year','click_month']].apply(lambda x : '{}{}'.format(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)

>>> df
  click_month click_year YearMonth
0          10       2014    201410
1          11       2015    201511
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, I tried this but it didn't show anything for some reasons and Anaconda kept crashing!!!

Comment: Care to explain downvote ?