# Combine pandas string columns with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to concat the strings in 2 or more columns of a pandas dataframe.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python), which works fine if you don't have any missing value. Unfortunately, I have, and this leads to things like "ValueA; None", which is not really clean.

Example data:

```
col_A  | col_B
------ | ------
val_A  | val_B 
None   | val_B 
val_A  | None 
None   | None
```

I need this result:

```
col_merge
---------
val_A;val_B
val_B
val_A
None
```

Comment: have you tried using fillna with an empty string '' on col_b?

Comment: Just did, but in case I have a NaN in the first columns, I get ";val_B". With Nan in both columns I just get ";"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `if-else`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: None if x.isnull().all() else ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
print (df)
0    val_A;val_B
1          val_B
2          val_A
3           None
dtype: object
```

For faster solution is possible use:

```
#add separator and replace NaN to empty space
#convert to lists
arr = df.add('; ').fillna('').values.tolist()
#list comprehension, replace empty spaces to NaN
s = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip('; ') for x in arr]).replace('^$', np.nan, regex=True)
#replace NaN to None
s = s.where(s.notnull(), None)
print (s)
0    val_A;val_B
1          val_B
2          val_A
3           None
dtype: object
```

---

```
#40000 rows
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: arr = df.add('; ').fillna('').values.tolist()
    ...: s = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip('; ') for x in arr]).replace('^$', np.nan, regex=True)
    ...: s.where(s.notnull(), None)
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 74 ms per loop


In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: df.apply(lambda x: None if x.isnull().all() else ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
    ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 12.7 s per loop

#another solution, but slowier a bit
In [72]: %%timeit
     ...: arr = df.add('; ').fillna('').values  
     ...: s = [''.join(x).strip('; ') for x in arr]
     ...: pd.Series([y if y != '' else None for y in s])
     ...: 
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
```

Comment: nice answer to a surprisingly hard problem. `.join()` and `.cat()` both surprisingly fail here

Comment: I'm not sure why, but all solutions I found, including the top solution always gave me a separator, like the "; ", if col_B was empty. The 'faster' solution was the only way I found to concatenate values with a separator and handle np.nans in the second column. Thank you Mr Jazrael once again!