# Combine Pandas columns containing list objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My question is similar to '[Combine pandas string columns with missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976585/combine-pandas-string-columns-with-missing-values)
' and '[How to merge/combine columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563833/how-to-merge-combine-columns-in-pandas)' but as the cells I want to combine contain lists, all the given answers don't work.

Simplified, my df looks like this:

```
        players    players1    players2    players3
1       ['1','2']  
2       ['2','4']
3                  ['1','4']
4                              ['1','5']
5                                          ['3','5']
6
7                  ['3','4']
```

(So i know there will never be values in two of the columns.)

Now I want to add a new column combining the lists:

```
        players    players1    players2    players3     players_combine
1       ['1','2']                                       ['1','2']
2       ['2','4']                                       ['2','4']
3                  ['1','4']                            ['1','4']
4                              ['1','5']                ['1','5']
5                                          ['3','5']    ['3','5']
6
7                  ['3','4']                            ['3','4']
```

I tried many things - mainly variations of the linked answers, my last idea was a cascading np.where. But it didn't work. Only the values from 'players' showed up in the combined column.

```
df['players_combine'] = np.where(df.players.notnull(),df.players.values,np.where(df.players1.notnull(),df.players1.values,np.where(df.players2.notnull(),df.players2.values,np.where(df.players3.notnull(),df.players3.values,np.nan))))
```

EDIT:
As asked in the comments: df.head(5).to_dict()

```
{'players': {'5b41800eaffb061b88c4beac': ['57005', '124021', '132037', '78523', '111742', '133892', '76431', '78066', '138749', '132358', '77857', '69756', '133745', '278877', '247798', '108106', '127464', '296770'], '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bead': ['18929', '110183', '28401', '302853', '296768', '94912', '93671', '52060', '43282', '132364', '140646', '77861', '19787', '133790', '312666', '76336', '317219', '137849'], '5b41800daffb061b88c4bc7f': 'nan', '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd62': 'nan', '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd65': 'nan'}, 'players1': {'5b41800eaffb061b88c4beac': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bead': nan, '5b41800daffb061b88c4bc7f': ['57005', '124021', '132037', '78523', '111742', '133892', '296770', '78066', '138749', '132358', '77857', '69756', '133745', '278877', '247798', '108106', '127464', '76431'], '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd62': '', '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd65': ''}, 'players2': {'5b41800eaffb061b88c4beac': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bead': nan, '5b41800daffb061b88c4bc7f': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd62': ['57005', '124021', '132037', '78523', '111742', '133892', '296770', '108106', '138749', '132358', '77857', '69756', '133745', '278877', '247798', '78066', '127464', '76431'], '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd65': ''}, 'players3': {'5b41800eaffb061b88c4beac': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bead': nan, '5b41800daffb061b88c4bc7f': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd62': nan, '5b41800eaffb061b88c4bd65': ['57005', '124021', '132037', '78523', '111742', '133892', '296770', '108106', '138749', '132358', '247798', '69756', '133745', '278877', '77857', '78066', '127464', '76431']}}
```

Comment: can you post `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: You cannot have "no values" in Pandas cells. What exactly do you have in them? Empty strings, empty lists, nans?

Comment: What's the empty value in those other columns? Is it an empty string, or NaN, or an empty list?

Comment: Yeah, good question. Most of them seem to have np.nan - but strangely, when I combined the cells into lists in one of my efforts, some of the lists looked like this: ['', '', [1,3], nan]. I guess these are empty strings?

Comment: if you post `d = df.to_dict()`, we can simply do `pd.DataFrame(d)` and reproduce the data frame exactly as is :)

Comment: @RafaelC Are you aiming at the same information - what is inside the empty cells?

Comment: @RafaelC Ah ok. The df is huge (40.000 rows). But i can try to make an excerpt.

Comment: @J_Scholz then just do `df.head(5).to_dict()` ;)

Comment: Edited original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some bad formatted data was the problem in my code and not the question asked, I wanted to add some information about the performance of all the different options. I used np.where because it uses vectorization whereas np.apply iterates through rows and therefore there is a huge performance difference.

---

Setting up test-df with 4*2000=8000 rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = [[['1','2'],np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
     [np.NaN,['2','3'],np.NaN,np.NaN],
    [np.NaN,np.NaN,['3','4'],np.NaN],
    [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,['4','5']]]

l=l*2000

df = pd.DataFrame(l)

df.columns = ['players','players1','players2','players3']
```

---

Best option:

```
%timeit df['players_combine'] = np.where(df.players.notnull(),df.players.values,np.where(df.players1.notnull(),df.players1.values,np.where(df.players2.notnull(),df.players2.values,np.where(df.players3.notnull(),df.players3.values,np.nan))))

100 loops, best of 3: 2.18 ms per loop
```

Very good option:

```
%timeit df.loc[df.notnull().any(axis=1)]\
  .apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)

100 loops, best of 3: 413 ms per loop
```

Other option 1:

```
%timeit df['players_combine'] = df.agg(lambda s: s[~s.isnull()][0], axis=1)

1 loop, best of 3: 4.71 s per loop
```

And 2:

```
%timeit df['players_combine'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].max(), axis=1)

1 loop, best of 3: 4.86 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If any of the empty cells is an empty string (`''`), first make it a NaN:

```
df[df==''] = np.nan
```

Then, select the maximum of all non-NaNs in each row:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].max(), axis=1)
#1    [1, 2]
#2    [2, 4]
#3    [1, 4]
#4    [1, 5]
#5    [3, 5]
#6       NaN
#7    [3, 4]
```

Another interesting (and **faster**) solution is to eliminate the all-NaN rows and then find the first valid value in each row:

```
df.loc[df.notnull().any(axis=1)]\
  .apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
#1    [1, 2]
#2    [2, 4]
#3    [1, 4]
#4    [1, 5]
#5    [3, 5]
#7    [3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, the np.where solution is even faster than this. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know you will only a value in at most a single column for each row, you can replace the values you don't care about with `NaN` and then use `.stack`.

In this case it looks like you have both `'nan'` and `''` strings which should be replaced with `np.NaN` first.

```
import numpy as np

df['players_combine'] = df.replace({'': np.NaN, 'nan': np.NaN}, regex=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'players': [['1','2'], '', '', np.NaN, ''],
                   'players1': ['', ['2','4'], '', np.NaN, ''],
                   'players2': ['', '', ['1','5'], np.NaN, ''],
                   'players3': ['', '', np.NaN, ['3', '5'], '']})
```

#### Output:

```
  players players1 players2 players3 players_combine
0  [1, 2]                                     [1, 2]
1           [2, 4]                            [2, 4]
2                    [1, 5]      NaN          [1, 5]
3     NaN      NaN      NaN   [3, 5]          [3, 5]
4                                                NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing your `df.to_dict()` it seems like, for some cells, you have the **string** `nan`, for others your have the actual `np.nan` and, for some others, you even have empty strings `''`.

So first clean your data set by making null values uniform:

```
df = df.replace({'nan':np.nan, '':np.nan})
```

Then you can [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) through the `axis=1`

```
df['players_combine'] = df.agg(lambda s: s[~s.isnull()][0], axis=1)
```

Comment: So it looks like the 'nan' were my problem all the time. I took them for real np.nan. Now my np.where line works.