# Pandas: concatenate a list of columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if I could build such a module in Pandas:

```
    def concatenate(df,columnlist,newcolumn):
        # df is the dataframe and
        # columnlist is the list contains the column names of all the columns I want to concatnate
        # newcolumn is the name of the resulted new column

        for c in columnlist:
            ...some Pandas functions

        return df # this one has the concatenated "newcolumn"
```

I am asking this because that len(columnlist) is going to be very big and dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: `I am wondering if...` - You will never know until you try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
np.add.reduce(df[columnlist], axis=1)
```

What this does is to "add" the values in each row, which for strings means to concatenate them ("abc" + "de" == "abcde").

---

Originally I thought you wanted to concatenate them lengthwise, into a single longer series of all the values.  If anyone else wants to do that, here's the code:

```
pd.concat(map(df.get, columnlist)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks John! I guess you misunderstood my original request @John Zwinck: if Column A is "ABC" and Column B is "XYZ" my newcolumn should be "ABCXYZ". The newcolumn has the exact length of the dataframe.

Comment: @LarryZ: I see.  I've changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @John Zwinck. It worked! It seems this method requires all the columns to be str, when any column contains int or float it will give the following error:  " TypeError: must be str, not float "

Comment: @LarryZ: You can fix that by `np.add.reduce(df[columnlist].astype(str), axis=1)`.

Comment: Thanks, man! This is the answer, period! A shameless followup question: What if I also want to add a "separator" between columns? i.e. instead of "ABCXYZ" I want "ABC XYZ"?  A dumb way is to add a new column called "Space" - contains nothing but one space " ", then insert the column name "Sapace" to my columnlist where necessary, it worked fine. Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: @LarryZ: I think that's a fine solution (using a Series with the separator).

Answer (score 9):

Given a dataframe like this:

```
df

     A    B
0  aaa  ddd
1  bbb  eee
2  ccc  fff
```

You can just use `df.sum`, given every column is a string column:

```
df.sum(1)

0    aaaddd
1    bbbeee
2    cccfff
dtype: object
```

If you need to perform a conversion, you can do so:

```
df.astype(str).sum(1)
```

If you need to select a subset of your data (only string columns?), you can use `select_dtypes`:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=['str']).sum(1)
```

If you need to select by columns, this should do:

```
df[['A', 'B']].sum(1)
```

In every case, the addition is not inplace, so if you want to persist your result, please *assign it back*:

```
r = df.sum(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, @COLDSPEED. Your solution appears promising. I tried "df.select_dtypes(include=['str']).sum(1)" but get this error below:   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2369, in select_dtypes
    invalidate_string_dtypes(dtypes)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 497, in invalidate_string_dtypes
    raise TypeError("string dtypes are not allowed, use 'object' instead")
TypeError: string dtypes are not allowed, use 'object' instead

Comment: Then when I change the code to df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).sum(1), it gave no error but the result is one column with all "0". Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @LarryZ what are your column types initially?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for the followup. A number of the columns contains mixed data type, both str and int. These columns are labeled as "object"

Comment: @LarryZ Select_dtypes may not work but everything else should.