# Panda: Create a column using first 2 letters from a text column

Tags: python, pandas

How to create a column using first 2 letters from other columns but not including NaN? E.g. I have 3 columns

```
a=pd.Series(['Eyes', 'Ear', 'Hair', 'Skin'])

b=pd.Series(['Hair', 'Liver', 'Eyes', 'NaN'])

c=pd.Series(['NaN', 'Skin', 'NaN', 'NaN'])

df=pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=1)

df.columns=['First', 'Second', 'Third']
```

Now I want to create a 4th column that would combine first 2 letters from 'First', 'Second' and 'Third' after sorting (**so that Ear comes before Hair irrespective of the column)**. But it would skip NaN values.

The final output for the fourth column would would look something like:

```
Fourth = pd.Series(['EyHa', 'EaLiSk', 'EyHa', 'Sk'])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python, you just need slice firstly and add them together

Answer (score 2):

If `NaN` is `np.nan` - missing value:

```
a=pd.Series(['Eyes', 'Ear', 'Hair', 'Skin'])
b=pd.Series(['Hair', 'Liver', 'Eyes', np.nan])
c=pd.Series([np.nan, 'Skin', np.nan, np.nan])
df=pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=1)
df.columns=['First', 'Second', 'Third']

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([y[:2] for y in x if pd.notnull(y)])), axis=1)
```

Another solution:

```
df['new'] = [''.join([y[:2] for y in x]) for x in np.sort(df.fillna('').values, axis=1)]
#alternative
#df['new'] = [''.join(sorted([y[:2] for y in x if pd.notnull(y)])) for x in df.values]
print (df)

  First Second Third     new
0  Eyes   Hair   NaN    EyHa
1   Ear  Liver  Skin  EaLiSk
2  Hair   Eyes   NaN    EyHa
3  Skin    NaN   NaN      Sk
```

If `NaN` is `string`:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([y[:2] for y in x if y != 'NaN'])), axis=1)

df['new'] = [''.join(sorted([y[:2] for y in x if y != 'NaN'])) for x in df.values]
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey - thank you for comment, in question there are `NaN`s as strings, but in real it is missing values, so add solutions for both situtations.

Comment: Yes NaN are missing values. I tried you approach and got an error message: ("'int' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0'). Any idea why is it so?

Comment: @DshM - I think there are some numeric values, try `df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted([str(y)[:2] for y in x if pd.notnull(y)])), axis=1)`