# pandas applying function to columns array is very slow

Tags: pandas

```
  os  hour  day
0  13    14    0
1  19    14    0
2  13    14    0
3  13    14    0
4  13    14    0
```

Here is my dataframe and I just want to get a new column which is `str(os)+'_'+str(hour)+'_'str(day)`. I use apply function to process the dataframe but it is very slow. 
Any high-performance method to realize this ?
I also tried convert the df to array and process every row. It seems that it is slow too.
There are nearly two hundred millions rows of the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried just do `df['new'] = df['os'].astype(str) + '_' +df['hour'].astype(str) + '_' + df['day'].astype(str)`?

Comment: Well, I tried this but it is also very slow.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19377969/2901002), I think fastest is `df['new'] = df['os'].map(str) + '_' +df['hour'].map(str) + '_' + df['day'].map(str)` if no `NaN`s

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what code are you using but you can try

```
df.astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis = 1)

0    13_14_0
1    19_14_0
2    13_14_0
3    13_14_0
4    13_14_0
```

Comment: Or `df.astype(str).agg('_'.join, axis=1)`!