# Pandas .astype(str).sum() with separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in a df: Name and Year and i want to concatenate them.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python) answer the best solution (and the fastest in my experience as well) is:

```
df[['Year','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

This results in something like:

```
Adam2013
John2014
```

What i would need is:

```
Adam 2013
John 2014
```

Meaning that i would need them separated by `' '`.

Is there a way to do this without compromision on speed?
Thanks!

> EDIT:

I did find a solution but i don't regard it as pretty:

Create an artificial column:

```
df['separator'] = ' '
```

Merge the columns with the separators in place:

```
df[['Year','separator','quarter']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
```

Get rid of the separator column:

```
df.drop(['separator'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: my friend, did u at least read what i asked?

Comment: Yes, now again. `df['quarter'] + ' ' + df['Year'].astype(str)` does not work?

Comment: Sorry, I forget for `' '`

Comment: but yes, this solution also works