# Combine cells from one column into one string

Tags: python, pandas, list, combiners

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename.csv)
corpus = df.corpus
```

How can I combine series of text strings (from one column) into a list?

from column 'corpus':
row 1: Hail Mary.
row 2: Hi Bob.
row 3: Hey Sue.

into
[Hail Mary. Hi Bob. Hey Sue.]

Looking for a list with len(list)=1.

Comment: A column of text in what? You haven't shown what the file type is, let alone how you're reading it. I also don't understand "Looking for a list with `len(list)=1`."

Comment: `[''.join(your_list)]` something like this?

Comment: Please show the code with the construct which stores your text.

Comment: @mad 
Tried that already, returns a str object. I'd like a list.

Comment: how will it return a string if encapsulated by `[` and `]` @spacedustpi

Comment: @Yunnosch its from pd.read_csv.

Comment: And that keeps you from showing any code to help people understand and answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Comment: @Yunnosch you'll need to clarify your question please.

Comment: @mad, those are columns, not rows they are working with in that link.

Comment: @spacedustpi Thanks for growing the chat area without providing the https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay, I will post all the techniques that I tried. I was just trying to keep all the excess off as much as possible, but it seems this is not as easy as I thought. Which I guess boosts my ego.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
df = pd.read_csv(your_file)
l = [' '.join(df['col'])]
```

Input:

```
          col
0  Hail Mary.
1     Hi Bob.
2    Hey Sue.
```

Output:

```
['Hail Mary. Hi Bob. Hey Sue.']
```

Comment: It actually works too with the square brackets and omitting '.tolist()'

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

result = [' '.join([row for row in df['column_name']])]
```

Output of `result`:

```
['Hail Mary. Hi Bob. Hey Sue.']
```

Comment: This technique yields a string object. Not a list.

Comment: It returns a `list` containing a single `string`. The brackets `[...]` around the `join` give you a `list`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does. Even simpler is result = [' '.join(df['column_name'])] -thanks.

Answer (score 0):

test.csv:

Hail Mary.
Hi Bob.
Hey Sue.

python:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('test.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        data.append(row.strip())
print data
```

output:
['Hail Mary.', 'Hi Bob.', 'Hey Sue.']

Comment: As per OP's comments, the combine should work on rows and not columns. `row` in your case will contain all the columns in the single row. Hopefully, you can edit your answer once he posts something otherwise it will be downvoted

Comment: @Christopher, this sort of works, but I'd skip the first row because it brings in the column labels into the list. In addition, the list length comes out to 5, I was looking for length of 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
    my_list = []

    for i in range(1,ws.max_row):
        if(len(my_list) == 0):
            my_list.append(ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value)   #assuming the value in 1st column
        else:
            my_list[0] += ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value

    for i in my_list:
        print(i)
```

Comment: This isn't pandas syntax, it looks like you're using an Excel reader. I don't understand how this deals with the OP's problem

Comment: I'm working with millions of lines, so I would not use this option even if we worked the kinks out. For loops are notoriously slow with big data sets.