# Concatenate columns of a dataframe with a separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python) with 88 upvotes but it doesn't work anymore:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
     [['USA', 'Nevada', 'Las Vegas'],
      ['Brazil', 'Pernambuco', 'Recife']],
     columns=['Country', 'State', 'City']
 )
df['AllTogether'] = df['Country'].str.cat(df[['State', 'City']], sep=' - ')
```

I get the error:

```
    raise ValueError("Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword?")
ValueError: Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword?
```

Not sure what has changed since the posted answer.

I have pandas version of `0.22.0`. I can't update the version due to test reasons.

Edit:
I am not looking for alternate answer but the concern is about the error.

Comment: Can't reproduce in 0.23.4.  Works fine for me

Comment: What is the expected output? Are you looking for df[['Country','State', 'City']].apply('-'.join, axis = 1)?

Comment: Yes it is concatenate columns with a given separator but I was more concerned with the error than alternate methods

Comment: I think they fix the issue in the version 0.23.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error in `pandas '0.21.1'`, but it appears to be a bug (which @Wen pointed out is now fixed in `pandas 0.23.4`). Regardless, you seem to be able to get around it by using `df[['State', 'City']].values` instead of just `df[['State', 'City']]`, *i.e* by supplying a `np.array` instead of a dataframe (which is not the normal behaviour, seeing as the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) state you can pass it a dataframe):

```
df['AllTogether'] = df['Country'].str.cat(df[['State','City']].values,sep=' - ')
>>> df
  Country       State       City                  AllTogether
0     USA      Nevada  Las Vegas    USA - Nevada - Pernambuco
1  Brazil  Pernambuco     Recife  Brazil - Las Vegas - Recife
```

Comment: This might help someone with an older version of pandas, reopening it. +1