# Combine multiple columns for each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is similar to this one: [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

However, I want to combine multiple columns, some of which are text and some are non-text. Moreover, I would like to do it in a loop, row by row because I need to preprocess the resulting text

I tried:

```
 for i in range(len(df)):
      text = df.loc[i, text_cols].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(str(x)))
```

`text_cols` is a parameter.

But it seems the result is not a text but an array of chars...

**Update**:
It seems the following solution works:

```
  text = ''
  for col in text_cols:
    text += ' ' + str(df.loc[i,col])
```

I wonder if there is a more fancy solution for it.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? I have posted a answer where you can iterate row by row and do the pre processing. But I will need to have a look at your df to help you. Please post df.head() here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `iterrows:`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    "Pre-process your data here"
    "To process particular row you can do this"
    row["column_name to process"]
```

Comment: the labels of columns is a parameter `text_cols`

Comment: I added an update to my question, your solution is too general