# How I can merge the columns into a single column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge 3 columns into a single column.  I have tried changing the column types. However, I could not do it.

For example, I have 3 columns such as `A: {1,2,4}, B:{3,4,4}, C:{1,1,1}`

Output expected: ABC Column `{131, 241, 441}`

My inputs are like this:

```
df['ABC'] = df['A'].map(str) + df['B'].map(str) + df['C'].map(str)

df.head()

ABC {13.01.0 , 24.01.0, 44.01.0}
```

The type of ABC seems object and I could not change via `str`, `int`.

```
df['ABC'].apply(str)
```

Also, I realized that there are NaN values in A, B, C column. Is it possible to merge these even with NaN values?

Comment: You should see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python). It answers basically the same question.

Comment: @Pedreo: No it doesnt... because the frame has NaNs

Comment: @Omer how do you want the NaNs to be included in the final output? and please update your question including NaN in your example table. Otherwise you won't get a correct answer

Comment: @Mack123456 True! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well technically, based on the current example df given, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# Example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

# Considering NaN's in the data-frame
df['colA'] = [1,2,4, np.NaN,5]
df['colB'] = [3,4,4,3,np.NaN]
df['colC'] = [1,1,1,4,1]

# Using pd.isna() to check for NaN values in the columns
df['colA'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else str(int(x)))
df['colB'] = df['colB'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else str(int(x)))
df['colC'] = df['colC'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else str(int(x)))

# Filling the NaN values with a blank space
df = df.fillna('')

# Transform columns into string
df = df.astype(str)

# Concatenating all together
df['ABC'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: The problem in the dataframe is the NaN. I have no idea how your solution solves this. Because of the NaN the numbers are floats > 1.0 3.0 etc.. enhance OPs question.

Comment: Indeed.  Depending on what OP wants you can use: df['ABC'] = df.sum(axis=1).apply(int).astype(str). that would give a str as output.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround your NaN problem could look like this but now NaN will be 0

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,4, np.nan], 'B':[3,4,4,4], 'C':[1,np.nan,1, 3]})
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True).astype(int).applymap(str)
df['ABC'] = df['A'] + df['B'] + df['C']
```

output

```
    A   B   C   ABC
0   1   3   1   131
1   2   4   0   240
2   4   4   1   441
3   0   4   3   043
```