# Combining Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a CSV file with separate columns for `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second` and would like to know how to combine the time columns (`hour`, `minute`, `second`) into a readable timestamp so I can plot data versus time.

This is my CSV file `data.head(10)`:

```
     flt  yr  month  day  hr  ...   
0    1  2018      1   17  16  ...         
1    1  2018      1   17  16  ...         
2    1  2018      1   17  16  ...           
3    1  2018      1   17  16  ...           
4    1  2018      1   17  16  ...           
5    1  2018      1   17  16  ...           
6    1  2018      1   17  16  ...         
7    1  2018      1   17  16  ...         
8    1  2018      1   17  16  ...          
9    1  2018      1   17  16  ...
```

I expect the outcome to be, for example, a timestamp of 16:45:13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataframe["time"] = dataframe["hour"].map(str) + ":" + dataframe["minute"].map(str) + ":" + dataframe["second"].map(str)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19378497/7690862)
[another example](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/concatenate-two-columns-dataframe-pandas-python-2/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the source link!