# Writing contents from a text file to csv file on only one Column-How to?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have converted a pdf file to a text file. This text file is also converted to a csv file. My Problem is the contents in the csv file is written in multiple columns(A,B,C,D,E) whereas I wanted to write it in only one column ie Column A. How could i write the contents from these columns into only one column?

I've tried using merge function and concatenate function and join function but it was of no help.

here's my code

```
import os.path
import csv
import pdftotext
#Load your PDF
with open("crimestory.pdf", "rb") as f:
   pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Save all text to a txt file.
with open('crimestory.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n\n".join(pdf))

save_path = "/home/mayureshk/PycharmProjects/NLP/"

completeName_in = os.path.join(save_path, 'crimestory' + '.txt')
completeName_out = os.path.join(save_path, 'crimestoryycsv' + '.csv')

file1 = open(completeName_in)
In_text = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')

file2 = open(completeName_out, 'w')
out_csv = csv.writer(file2)

file3 = out_csv.writerows(In_text)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

The expected output in the csv file should be Column A
All information. Rest of the columns
Empty

Comment: Are you trying to produce something like `pd.melt()` would do or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35850749/4350650) answer ?

Comment: sort off. for eg.  the data in csv file is scattered like its everywhere from Column A to Column F. I want the data to be written only on column A itself. @Mayeulsgc

Comment: But do you want to keep the data of column A in a single cell or put Col A, Col B and Col C directly in in Col A, becoming (A+B+C) ?

Comment: I want to keep it directly in Column A. Becoming (A+B+C)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35850749/4350650) answer to merge all columns in one.

```py
#dummy df 
df =pd.DataFrame({'ColA':['value_A1','value_A2','value_A3','value_A4'],'ColB':['value_B1','value_B2','value_B3','value_B4'],'ColC':['value_C1','value_C2','value_C3','value_C4']})
```

I'll use pandas to load your csv:

```py
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv(sep=',',savepath+'crimestorycsv.csv')
df = df.astype(str)
col = df.columns
df['All'] = df[col[0]].str.cat(df[col[1:]],sep='|')
df.drop(col,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Results :

> All
>    0  value_A1|value_B1|value_C1
>    1  value_A2|value_B2|value_C2
>    2  value_A3|value_B3|value_C3
>    3  value_A4|value_B4|value_C4

Comment: I kindoff checked it by saving it to the file by using to_csv method just to ensure everything is right but the solution which you provided doesnt work at all. its not concatenating and its adding new column with their indexes(which i never wanted)

Comment: it is working on my dummy dataframe, i'll update adding my dataframe and the given results