# Make 2 cols into 1, not showing nan Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make `Address 2` and `Address 3` combined into a column. Originally I tried casting to a string and using its concatenate function like this:

```
df['newAdd2'] = df['Address 2'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Address 3'].astype(str), sep=' ')
```

(from here: [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19377969/1069659))

which gave the results like this:

```
VillageA TownA
nan nan
nan TownC
VillageD nan
```

I want to make `Address 3` added to `Address 2` (in a new column is fine). Sometimes `Address 3` is missing a value, sometimes `Address 2` is missing a value. This `if else` process is clunky (and might not even work...). What's a Pythonic way of doing it?

```
if df['Address 2']:
    if df['Address 3']:
        #concate 2 and 3
    else:
        #only show 2
else:
    if df['Address 3']:
        #only show 3
```

Comment: Can't you just do `df['Address 2'] + df['Address 3']`?

Comment: @EdChum yes. Yes I can. Doh

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to combine 2 columns into one, you can create a new column or use an existing column.

```
df['New Address']=pd.concat([df['Address 2'].dropna(),df['Address 3'].dropna()])
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment:

`df['Address 2'] + df['Address 3']`

pretty easy.... (doh)