# i want to reorder the data of a column then Split it to new columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to do this in python for 2 day but i have been unsuccessful.

Table:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might help:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/ (Specifically Example #2)

For reordering columns, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32131398/2566205

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to split the column ,but i am still having a problem with my output. I need to change the order of what is written in the cell. EX:'Elaboração e Normatização,Planejada'     to    'Planejada, , , ,Elaboração e Normatização

Comment: that would require joining back in a different order. If you split your column into a list (with a comma delimiter), you might be able to join such that last element comes first. Something to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python