# Python: Condense DataFrame column values into a single cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['Google','Yahoo','LinkedIn'], 
     'col2': ['Microsoft', 'Oracle', 'Uber']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How can I concatenate these columns values into single cells joined with "&", like:

```
       col1                          col2
0     'Google'&'Yahoo'&'LinkedIn'   'Microsoft'&'Oracle'&'Uber'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Comment: @PrachitiPrakashPrabhu Thanks for reminding me, but that does not answer my question. I clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

Just create a `list` from the `Series` (column) values and use the `str.join()` function to concatenate the values.  Then, add back into a new `DataFrame`.

#### Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initial dataset.
data1 = {'col1': ['Google','Yahoo','LinkedIn'], 
         'col2': ['Microsoft', 'Oracle', 'Uber']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

# Derived dataset.
data2 = {'col1': '&'.join(df['col1'].tolist()),
         'col2': '&'.join(df['col2'].tolist())}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=[0])
```

#### Output:

```
    col1                    col2
0   Google&Yahoo&LinkedIn   Microsoft&Oracle&Uber
```