# fill column from values of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of two columns col1 and col2 I want to fill column 3 from value col1 and col2.

```
df['col3'] = "122 (xxxxx): Don't show temp df['col1'] and df['col2']"
```

Does anyone knows how to do please?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"122 (xxxxx): Don't show temp {x['col1']} and {x['col2']}", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do

```
df['col3'] = "Text1" + df['col1'] + "Text2" + df['col2']
```

Might need to use .astype(str) if datatype is not string!