# How will I write an equivalent Python syntax for R syntax

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, join, regexp-replace

data$GroupId = paste( data$Surname, data$Pclass, sub('.$','X',data$Ticket), data$Fare, data$Embarked, sep='-')

Output:
[Output of the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWOCp.jpg)

Comment: Provide a sample of the input data, and explain what you want to achieve in the question and then people can help you with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
data['GroupId'] = data['Surname'] + data['Pclass'].astype(str).str.replace('$', 'X') + '-' + data['Fare'].astype(str) + data['Embarked'].astype(str)
```

I don't know types of your dataframe so I converted them all to strings.

If you want to see more [see this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Glad to hear. You can close the question then.