# How to merge hierarchial columns into 1 column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel sheet like below.

[image]

I want to merge all those hierarichial columns into 1 column like below using pandas

[image]

Is there any way to merge like that if yes please tell me how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19378497/6692898

Answer (score 2):

You can use [df.bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) with `axis = 1` then use `iloc` to extract first column

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None, None], [None, 2, None, None], [None, None, 3, None], [None, None, None, 4]])
>>> df
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
>>> df = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
>>> df
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```