# Create pandas columns programmatically based on existing columns and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create new columns in a pandas df based on values from existing columns.   Does anyone know a good way of doing that?

Basically I need to get the value from one column and create new colum using the value from another existing column as a name

df['a'], df['b'], df['c'], df['d']  - - -  so if the value in df['a'] is D then I need to create a new column name from value df['a'] and insert  the values from df['d'] in each row that matches this criteria

not sure if I was clear enough but I would appreciate any help.
the total columns would be more than 30, so I would like to know a smart way of doing that   instead of manually typing df['new column'] = df.apply .......

[DF with original columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZTBx.png)

```
def view_conv(activity, activityId, total_conv, view_conv, click_conv):
if activityId == '10649748':
    return view_conv



def click_conv(activity, activityId, total_conv, view_conv, click_conv):
if activityId == '10649748':
    return click_conv


d['Insights Programmes - STEM Internships Application Start - View-through Conversions'] = d[['Activity','Activity ID', 'Total Conversions', 'View-through Conversions', 'Click-through Conversions']].apply(lambda x: view_conv(*x), axis=1)

d['Insights Programmes - STEM Internships Application Start - Click-through Conversions'] = d[['Activity','Activity ID', 'Total Conversions', 'View-through Conversions', 'Click-through Conversions']].apply(lambda x: click_conv(*x), axis=1)
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovpXx.png)

I'm sure this is not the best way of doing this, there will be a few different values in column activity so I need to know a smarter way of doing this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @sophros thanks for this.  To be honest it doesn't. There are a  lot of different values in column df['a'] which  I will use to create new columns , around 30 new columns using values from df['a'] as name and values from other columns based on some condition.

Comment: Kindly share sample data with expected output

Comment: Any ideas guys? I appreciate any help