# Combine weekday with hours in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a weekday column that contains the name of the weekdays and a time column that contains hours on these days. How can I combine these 2 columns, so they can be also sortable?

I have tried the string version but it is not sortable based on weekdays and hours.

This is the sample table how it looks like.

| weekday | time |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 12:00 |
| Monday | 13:00 |
| Tuesday | 20:00 |
| Friday | 10:00 |

This is what I want to get.

| weekday_hours |
| --- |
| Monday 12:00 |
| Monday 13:00 |
| Tuesday 20:00 |
| Friday 10:00 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @deadshot op is not asking to just concat to two columns, they also wanted them sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that df is your initial dataframe

```
import json
datas = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
final_data = {"weekday_hours": []}
for data in datas:
    final_data["weekday_hours"].append(data['weekday'] + ' ' + data['time'])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_data)
final_df
```

Ouptput:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you first need to create a datetime object of 7 days at an hourly level to sort by. In a normal Data warehousing world you normally have a calendar and a time dimension with all the different representation of your date data that you can merge and sort by, this is an adaptation of that methodology.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range('01 Jan 2021', '08 Jan 2021',freq='H')})
df1['str_date'] = df1['date'].dt.strftime('%A %H:%M')

print(df1.head(5))

    date      str_date
0 2021-01-01 00:00:00  Friday 00:00
1 2021-01-01 01:00:00  Friday 01:00
2 2021-01-01 02:00:00  Friday 02:00
3 2021-01-01 03:00:00  Friday 03:00
4 2021-01-01 04:00:00  Friday 04:00
```

---

Then create your column to merge on.

```
df['str_date'] = df['weekday'] + ' ' +  df['time'] 

df2 = pd.merge(df[['str_date']],df1,on=['str_date'],how='left')\
                            .sort_values('date').drop('date',1)


print(df2)

 str_date
3   Friday 10:00
0   Monday 12:00
1   Monday 13:00
2  Tuesday 20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the question, you want a single column, "weekday_hours," but you also want to be able to sort the data based on this column. This is a bit tricky because "Monday" doesn't provide enough information to define a valid `datetime`. Parsing using `pd.to_datetime(df['weekday_hours'], format='%A %H:%M'` for example, will return `1900-01-01 <hour::minute::second>` if given just weekday and time. When sorted, this only sorts by time.

One workaround is to use `dateutil` to parse the dates. In lieu of a date, it will return the next date corresponding to the day of the week. For example, today (9 April 2021) `dateutil.parser.parse('Friday 10:00')` returns `datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 9, 10, 0)` and `dateutil.parser.parse('Monday 10:00')` returns `datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 12, 10, 0)`. Therefore, we need to set the "default" date to something corresponding to our "first" day of the week. Here is an example starting with unsorted dates:

```
    import datetime
import dateutil
import pandas as pd

weekdays = ['Friday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
times = ['10:00', '13:00', '12:00', '20:00', ]
df = pd.DataFrame({'weekday' : weekdays, 'time' : times})

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['weekday_hours'] = df[['weekday', 'time']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)

amonday = datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0) # assuming week starts monday
sorter = lambda t: [dateutil.parser.parse(ti, default=amonday) for ti in t]
print(df2.sort_values('weekday_hours', key=sorter))
```

Produces the output:

```
  weekday_hours
2   Monday 12:00
1   Monday 13:00
3  Tuesday 20:00
0   Friday 10:00
```

Note there are probably more computationaly efficient ways if you are working with a lot of data, but this should illustrate the idea of a sortable weekday/time pair.