# How to set condition on sep when we want to join string between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder if there is a way to join between strings from two columns of a data frame as I referred to this: [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe/57269756#57269756) But it seems like I cannot find the solution that satisfied my need. Suppose I have a data frame with two columns: First and Second. So the Third column should be sth like this:

```
df['Third'] = df.First.astype(str).str.cat(df.Second.astype(str), sep=',')
```

Normally, the concatenation works well when those 2 columns are string but in my case, the first and the second column can sometimes contain NaN

So Is there a way to set the condition on **sep** whether it needs to put or not in case for example: if df['First']= 'first' and df['Second'] = NaN then df['Third'] = 'first' without a **,** at the end. if df['first'] = NaN and df['Second'] = 'second' then df['Third'] = 'second' without a **,** at the beginning of the string.

How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how efficient this is, or if there's a better way.

If `first` and `second` are the only columns in the data frame:

```py
df["third"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: ",".join([x for x in row if not pd.isna(x)]),
    axis=1
)
```

If there are other columns:

```py
df["third"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: ",".join([x for x in row[["first", "second"]] if not pd.isna(x)]),
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: Can you specify which column to apply if we have the other columns than First and Second?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda and apply gets messy, so to make it clear you may want to just abstract out a function:

```
def my_join(a,b):
    if a != NaN and b != NaN: return a + ',' + b
    elif a == NaN return b
    else return a

df['Third'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_join(x.First, x.Second))
```

Comment: Did you include the ',' when those 2 are not NaN?