# Conditional concatenation on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe named IND_Split as:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   TY  50                  
1   TY  XT  50              
2   TY  100                 
3   TY  200                 
4   TY  500
```

What I desire :
to get a concatenated single column based on a condition - "if the value in next column is not blank then concatenate with **"%20"** in between else do not concatenate next column"

Desired output must look like:

```
    0                       
0   TY%2050                 
1   TY%20XT%2050                
2   TY%20100                    
3   TY%20200                    
4   TY%20500
```

What I have tried:

```
IND_Concat = IND_Split[0] + "%20" if IND_Split[1]!='' else ''.....
IND_Concat.head()
```

Output I got :

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911306/3376059
I think this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The above suggested method does not work for me! I need to conditionally put "%20". 
output from suggested method :
eg: TY%2050%20%20%20%20%20 
as you can see it unnecessarily adds %20 for columns 3 to 6, which is exactly I don't want!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df_out = df.apply(
    lambda x: "%20".join([v for v in x if str(v).strip()]), axis=1
).to_frame()
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
              0
0       TY%2050
1  TY%20XT%2050
2      TY%20100
3      TY%20200
4      TY%20500
```