# unite columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have csv file with duplicate columns but this row have don't same datas,i need to unite this columns withoute loss data/
example

| name | value | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pol | asd | fdas |

i want to have
this view

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| pol | asd*fdas |

i'm sorry for my english.
i have this columns

````
       'Год издания', 'Объем', 'Серия', 'ISBN', 'Цена', 'Темат. рубрика',
       'Ключевое слово', 'Ключевое слово.1', 'Ключевое слово.2',
       'Ключевое слово.3', 'Ключевое слово.4', 'Ключевое слово.5',
       'Ключевое слово.6', 'Ключевое слово.7', 'Ключевое слово.8',
       'Ключевое слово.9', 'Ключевое слово.10', 'Ключевое слово.11',
       'Ключевое слово.12', 'Ключевое слово.13', 'Ключевое слово.14',
       'Ключевое слово.15', 'Ключевое слово.16', 'Ключевое слово.17',
       'Ключевое слово.18', 'Ключевое слово.19', 'Ключевое слово.20',
       'Ключевое слово.21', 'Ключевое слово.22', 'Ключевое слово.23',
       'Ключевое слово.24', 'Ключевое слово.25', 'Ключевое слово.26',
       'Ключевое слово.27', 'Ключевое слово.28', 'Ключевое слово.29',
       'Ключевое слово.30', 'Ключевое слово.31', 'Ключевое слово.32',
       'Ключевое слово.33', 'Ключевое слово.34', 'Инд.ББК мас.биб',
       'Авторский знак', 'Расстановка', 'Инвентар.номер', 'Отдел библиотек',
       'Примеч к инв.N', 'Шт/код книги', 'Язык осн.текста', 'Сигла',
       'Кол.экземпляров'],
      dtype='object')```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have duplicate dataframe columns names, I would change them first like that:

```
df.columns = ['name', 'value1', 'value2']
```

And after that do the string manipulation:

```
df['value'] = df['value1'] + "*" + df['value2']
```

You can drop value1, value2 columns like that and keep only value:

```
df = df.drop(['value1', 'value2'], 1)
```