# How can I concatenate two integer columns inside pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, data-extraction

I am trying to combine the longitude and latitude columns so I can use to plot my points with GeoPandas. I tried concatenating the integers using:

```
df3['Location'] = df3['latitude'].astype(str) + ' ' +      df3['longitude'].astype(str)
```

But I get the following error:

> sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

I believe this is because the function only takes string.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3'], 'latitude': [42.14267,42.131203,42.131638], 'longitude':[-76.902040,-76.917860,-76.822420]})
```

This is my dataFrame now

```
 ID  latitude       longitude    
0  1      42.142677  -76.902040   
1  2      42.131203  -76.917860   
2  3      42.131638  -76.822420
```

But, I want my data frame to look like this. Just a new column, with each row showing the longitude and latitude coordinates separated by a comma and wrapped with
parentheses. ex. '(42.142677,-76.902040)'

```
  ID  latitude       longitude    location
0  1      42.142677  -76.902040   (42.142677,-76.902040)   
1  2      42.131203  -76.917860   (42.131203, -76.917860) 
2  3      42.131638  -76.822420   (42.131638,-76.822420)
```

Note: I apologize, For some reason the table above is not formatting properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the latitude and longitude columns to string first and try to concat later:

```
df3["latitude"] = df3["latitude"].astype(str)
df3["longitude"] = df3["longitude"].astype(str)

df3["location"] = "(" + df3["latitude"] + ", " + df3["longitude"] + ")"
```

You can also do it on the fly using the below code:

```
df3["location"] = "(" + df3["latitude"].astype(str) + ", " + df3["longitude"].astype(str) + ")"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve exactly what you have requested. Two columns as a string **tuple** representation

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""" ID  latitude       longitude    
0  1      42.142677  -76.902040   
1  2      42.131203  -76.917860   
2  3      42.131638  -76.822420"""), sep="\s+")

df["location"] = df.drop(columns=["ID"]).apply(tuple, axis=1).astype(str)

df
```

| ID | latitude | longitude | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 42.1427 | -76.902 | (42.142677, -76.90204) |
| 2 | 42.1312 | -76.9179 | (42.131203, -76.91786) |
| 3 | 42.1316 | -76.8224 | (42.131638, -76.82242) |

For plotting this is not useful. Really you want as geometry

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(y=df["latitude"], x=df["longitude"]), crs="epsg:4386")

gdf.explore(marker_kwds={"radius":15}, height=300, width=400)
```

[image]