# Pandas how to merge all the rows json columns value into one row with single column as JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a task to upload MySQL table JSON data to the rest API. I am loading the data in the Pandas dataframe and transforming it and trying to make a single JSON value to post to the API endpoint.

The task is to collect all rows of MySQL table json column data and embeds it into a single JSON data to post all rows of JSON data in a single post request of Python.

Mysql table rows data example value as below -

| id | source | action | object_pk | json_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Update | 701 | [{"keys": {"PlayerID": "701"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}}] |
| 2 | A | Update | 702 | [{"keys": {"PlayerID": "702"}, "values": {"EMail": "dbe@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "Female", "Street": "Abc", "Balance": 500, "BrandId": 2, "Country": "GR", "Currency": "EURO", "Language": "gr"}}] |

After loading, this data into the pandas dataframe would like to merge all rows of JSON data into a single valid JSON data.

Trying for expected output as below in Pandas df -

| json_data |
| --- |
| [{"keys": {"PlayerID": "701"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}},{"keys": {"PlayerID": "702"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}}] |

My goal is to load mysql table data every 10 minutes interval and send all rows of JSON data in a single post to the rest API endpoint.

```
r = requests.post("https://abc/rowset", json=json_data,headers=headers)
```

Not sure how to accomplish this in Pandas. Any pointers or code samples will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can easily convert a Pandas column into a list: `df['json_data'].to_list()`. But IMHO, using Pandas for such a task is really overkill: just extract the required column from the table directly in Python and make a json from the query dataset.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - to_list() not returning valid json.its return the data as - ['[{"keys": {"PlayerID": "701"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}}]', '[{"keys": {"PlayerID": "702"}, "values": {"EMail": "dbe@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "Female", "Street": "Abc", "Balance": 500, "BrandId": 2, "Country": "GR", "Currency": "EURO", "Language": "gr"}}]']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, the content of the `json_data` column is a (json) string representation of a list containing one single element which is a dict. IFAIK, there is no way to directly convert that column to a single json.

A possible way is to:

1. convert each element to a valid list
2. extract the first (and single) element of that list
3. make a list from all of those elements
4. convert the list to a json string

It could be implemented as:

```
import json

...
js = json.dumps([json.loads(elt)[0] for elt in df['json_data']])
```

with your shown data, I got:

```
'[{"keys": {"PlayerID": "701"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}}, {"keys": {"PlayerID": "702"}, "values": {"EMail": "dbe@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "Female", "Street": "Abc", "Balance": 500, "BrandId": 2, "Country": "GR", "Currency": "EURO", "Language": "gr"}}]'
```

Comment: Thank you .Using this code hint, I am getting the data as expected.Also as you are suggesting instead of Pandas , I will try with Python cursor to get the data from MySQL table and then concat each rows JSON data and make a single JSON data before posting it to rest API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but you can try something like this:

```py
df['json_data'].to_dict()
```

This should return a `dict` which is technically a JSON-looking file, where each row index will be the key & whole `df['json_data']` column as value, i.e.:

```py
{
0: '[{"keys": {"PlayerID": "701"}, "values": {"EMail": "abc@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "male", "Street": "kolol", "Balance": 2000, "BrandId": 1, "Country": "US", "Currency": "USD", "Language": "en"}}]'
1: '[{"keys": {"PlayerID": "702"}, "values": {"EMail": "dbe@gmail.com", "Active": "activenotverified", "Gender": "Female", "Street": "Abc", "Balance": 500, "BrandId": 2, "Country": "GR", "Currency": "EURO", "Language": "gr"}}]'
}
```

etc.
Not sure why each `json_data` row is in `[]` brackets, maybe you would want to remove them from with the help of `substr` or any similar method.

[more about `to_dict()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: [] brackets i am using as SalesForce they have given the example data.I can keep the data without [] also as valid JSON.[link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html)