# How to find what causes a KeyError in a Python CSV program

Tags: python, pandas, csv, output

I want to combine the 3 columns `Name_1`, `Name_2` and `Name_3` to one `Name`.

Here is the **new** script:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", sep=r'\\t', engine='python')

# Combine cells in a specific column
df['Name'] = df[['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3']].apply(' '.join, axis=1)

# Save the result to a new CSV file
df.to_csv("Test-new.csv", index=False)
```

**CSV example as file:** https://filehorst.de/d/erbwxyuJ

**CSV example as code (separated by tabs):**

```
LFNR    Name_1  Name_2  Name_3  Strasse Plz Ort Telefon Telefax
4       Wxxxxx.xe   KxxxxY- XxY XxxxxxxxxxxY    XxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxY 25   11111   XxxxxxY 0123-1231230    0123-1231231
24  Fxxxx   Kxxxx Rxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxk xxY Hxxxxxxxxxxxf Xxxx X xx. XX Ix Xxxxxxh 5    0123    KxxxY   012312-12312    012312-123123
25          Bxxxxxxxxxx Kxxxxxx Sxxxxxxxxxxxx Sxxxxx 123    0123    Cxxxxxx 0123 123123 0123 1231231
```

When I start the script I get this error:

```
C:\Users\s.123\Downloads\python>Test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s.123\Downloads\python\Test3.py", line 7, in <module>
    df['Name'] = df[['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3']].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
                 ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\s.123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3767, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\s.123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5876, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\s.123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5935, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Supposing you just want to concatenate the columns separated by a space, you can simply write :

    `df["Name"] = df["Name1"] + " " + df["Name2"] + " " + df["Name3"]`

Comment: Oh i forgot, It´s separated by a tabulator.

Comment: for more discussion on concatenation of columns , [combine two columns and create new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please provide a MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)), instead of images. (We need samples to **work** with, not only to **look** at.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for editing. I hope now it´s ok with my new informations.

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple string columns together nice & neatly using `.apply`.

To concatenate each value with one space in between:

```
df['Name'] = df[['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3']].apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```